# eww bookmark mangagement?

Tags: bookmarks, eww

I've found myself using the eww web browser more and more for text-based sites (e.g., documentation, news, etc.) This is great because I don't have to load an external GUI browser and leave emacs. Meanwhile, I've created a fairly large set of eww bookmarks over time. The problem is that I have some duplicates as well as some bookmarks that are no longer operational or relevant. How do I go about deleting these? Better yet, how can I organize these? The eww documentation is rather weak and nothing jumped out at me as for what to do. So does anybody have a bookmark solution for eww already?

Answer (score 5):

For posterity, you can delete EWW bookmarks simply by `C-k` (or `M-x eww-bookmark-kill`) in the `*eww bookmarks*` buffer.

Answer (score 3):

[Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) gives you lots of ways to manage sets of normal Emacs bookmarks, including for EWW.

It also offers several unique possibilities for bookmarking URLs with EWW, if you use Emacs 25 or later.

You can convert your existing EWW "bookmarks" (which are *not* normal Emacs bookmarks) to normal Emacs bookmarks.

From then on, you can just create normal Emacs bookmarks in EWW buffers.

Option `bmkp-eww-buffer-handling` controls how to handle EWW buffers:

> A `nil` value means always use buffer `*eww*` for EWW, and do not rename
>   the buffer.  This value makes no change to the behavior of EWW.
>
> Non-`nil` means rename the buffer using the web-page title.  This
>   affects EWW behavior even when bookmarks are not used.
>
> The particular non-`nil` value defines whether and when a
>   separate (e.g. new) buffer is used, and whether a reused existing
>   buffer is renamed, as follows:
>
> `one`         - Use one buffer for all EWW visits, renaming it.
>
> `url`         - Use a separate buffer for each URL.
>
> other non-`nil` - Use a separate buffer for each web-page visit.
>
> Except for a value of (`nil` or) `url`, the buffer is renamed to
>   `*eww*-` followed by the web-page title.
>
> For `url`, the buffer is renamed to `*eww*-` followed by the page
>   title, followed by a `SPC` char and the last 20 chars of the URL.
>   This generally means that different pages with the same title use
>   different buffers.

Minor mode `bmkp-eww-auto-bookmark-mode` sets a bookmark whenever you visit a URL with EWW.  (The bookmark name is the title of the web page.)
Option `bmkp-eww-auto-type` determines whether this automatic bookmarking only updates existing bookmarks or also creates new ones.

Boolean option `bmkp-eww-replace-keys-flag` controls whether to replace EWW bookmarking keys and menus with Bookmark+ ones.

Comment: Nice. I already know that eww bookmarks are not regular Emacs bookmarks (which i use regularly), but it looks like bookmark+ has just what I need to better manage bookmarks in general, including eww. Will try this out. Thanks!